# Синхронизация базы данных SQLite с базой данных Postgresql

Tags: база-данных, postgresql, sqlite

Есть готовая база Postgresql. Есть идентичная база данных SQLite.

Есть ли такой инструмент, который синхронизировал бы в РЕЖИМЕ ОНЛАЙН SQLite базу с базой Postgresql?Имеется ввиду, что при добавлении строки в таблицу postgresql эта строка добавлялась бы и в таблицу SQLite и наоборот.

Не предлагайте, пожалуйста, вариант использовать просто одну бд, это известно.

Comment: То есть, нужна мастер-мастер синхронизация? То есть, модифицироваться могут обе таблицы?

и второй вопрос - это нужно для "побаловаться", для "домашнего задания в институте" или для "продакшена"?

Comment: До этого не был знаком с термином "мастер-мастер синхронизация", да именно это и нужно. Модифицироваться могут обе таблицы. Пока что интерес чисто гипотетический, подбираю более оптимальное решение для продакшена.

Comment: Мастер-мастер как раз подразумевает модификацию обеих таблиц. Скажу сразу - камней подводных будет уйма и лучше так не делать. Единственное, что могу посоветовать, так это то, что ключи нужно делать непересекающиеся. В одной базе чётные, в другой нечётные. Так будет легче.

Comment: А как бы вы посоветовали лучше сделать?

Comment: Я бы рекомендовал использовать две однотипные базы (то есть постгрес и постгрес) и между ними сделать синхронизацию. Например, как здесь http://devppp.blogspot.com/2014/01/master-master-postgreesql-bucardo.html

Вопрос только в том, в чем у Вас задача.

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/457319/%D0%91%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B0-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-android-%D0%B8-%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B0-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B0/ Вот в принципе задача

Comment: Вот это сразу нужно писать. Как я бы делал. На сервере база, для нее написана обертка, что то в стиле rest. Клиент, когда ему нужно сделать запрос, смотрит, есть ли в его личной базе нужная запись, если нет - бежит на сервер и запрашивает их. А также сохраняет в локальной базе. Остается только решить проблему с синхронизацией, если клиент не уверен в свежести данных - он отправляет на сервер временную метку своих данных и сервер сравнивает с своими. Если это актуальные данные - то сервер просто отвечает кодом 304.

Comment: Понял вашу идею. Буду думать, большое спасибо!