# База данных android и база данных сайта

Tags: android, база-данных, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, sqlite

Есть приложение Ruby On Rails, которое использует базы данных Postgresql, все работает на VPS.

Как связать android приложение с этой базой данных? Я так понял, что android-приложение использует SQLite... Как сделать онлайн синхронизацию бд SQLite и бд postgresql?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

для этого вам нужно создать протокол взаимодейтвия с сервером.

1. Создаете скрипт (API) на сервере работающий с БД postgres
2. Создаете модуль на Android который обращается в API
3. Создаете модуль синхронизации баз который работает с модулем API и БД SQlite

на прямую работать с базой на сервере не рекомендуется. Лучше воспользоваться этим методо.